# How to setup cmusphinx with lua?

Tags: lua, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

So I wanted to go about designing an add-on for a game I play, World of Warcraft and the game uses Lua scripts. The add-on involves speech recognition. I found a library that apparently adds voice recognition functionality to Lua.

Here is the link to the library: https://github.com/stuarch/speechtotxt-lua

The problem is, I have no idea how to set this up. It looks like they're using linux commands, but can I use this with Windows?

Also, do I have to put all these files in a certain place (pocketsphinx, sphinxbase) like a project folder, and then call them from Lua?

I'm sorry if this a noob question, I just can't find anything online about adding these libraries to Lua, and how to include the pocketsphinx and sphinx base. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't you think naming the game would help? Just because your game can run Lua scripts doesn't mean you can do anything. Usually access to the operating system library as well as loading external libraries is prohibited in such an environment.

Comment: Oh ya, sorry. its World of Warcraft.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between let's say running the full Lua interpreter under Windows and running a Lua interpreter as part of a software like WoW.

They usually restrict the use of Lua to what makes sense for the game. You don't have to reboot the system from within WoW, you also should not be able to manipulate files or even manipulate memory ....

Just imagine you install a WoW addon from the internet and it suddenly deletes all files on your computer. Whooops.

So they simply remove the standard Lua libraries like os, debug, io...

Of course they also don't want you to extend your power beyond those limitations by loading third party code. Hence they remove the require function.

So all you can do in WoW is run restricted Lua code and use the feature set they offer you.
Adding speach recognition to WoW is not possible through the embedded Lua interpreter.

Comment: Ah, well ce la vie. Thanks for clarifying.